# Exception not getting translated

Tags: java, exception, junit, mocking, junit5

I have a method that makes a HTTP call like so:

```
public String executeRequest(HttpRequest request) {
    try {
      return httpResourceProvider.getHttpClient()
          .send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
          .body();
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
      log.atSevere().withCause(e).log("Could not do stuff");
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

In my unit test, I make the `send` method throw an `IOException` and then I verify that I get a `RuntimeException` like so:

```
  @Mock
  private HttpClient httpClient;

  // init mocks etc.

  @Test
  public void testRequestThrowsIOException() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    when(httpClient.send(eq(httpRequest), eq(HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()))).thenThrow(new IOException());
    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, () -> myRepository.getSchema(TEST_SCHEMA_ID));
  }
```

However my test fails due to an `IOException`. How is this happening?
Why is my code not translating the exception?

```
SEVERE: Could not call Github to fetch schema
java.io.IOException
    at *.executeRequest(*.java:33)
```

Note: `HttpResourceProvider` is mocked and returns the mock instance of `HttpRequest`

Comment: Your assertion is on `httpClient.send` **not** `executeRequest`. And **in** `executeRequest` you also use a `httpClient` and it **does** throw the `IOException`.

Comment: The `httpClient` instance is a mock instance returned by the `httpResourceProvider`. So `myRepository.getSchema()` calls `httpClient.send()`.

Comment: Your test is calling `myRepository.getSchema()`, but your snippet does not show this method, only `executeRequest()`, what is the relation of these 2 methods? Does the former call the latter? Are they in the same class? Can you provide the `myRepository.getSchema()` code?